# Multithreading in C++ with Lambda Expression

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda

I am implementing a client server application where server can handle more than one connection and in order to do this I am trying multi threading with lambda expressions. Below is my sample code.

```
void start() {
std::thread thread ([=]   { return serverConnect(port, IpAddr); } );
}
```

And my serverConnect code is

```
int serverConnect(int tcpPort, const string& hostname) {
    con = IedConnection_create();
    IedConnection_connect(con, &error, hostname.c_str(), tcpPort);
    std::cout << "Connection Status :" << error  << std::endl;
    return error;
}
```

What I exactly need is I need to print the connection status (variable error) in my start() function. Right now am printing in my serverConnect() function.

1. How  to do this ?
2. What exactly my thread will be having ?
3. How to store my lambda return value using my thread ?

Comment: I think to print the result in `start`, this function would have to wait for the completion of the thread, thus blocking execution anyway, which would make the thread pointless. Why do you want to print the result in `start`?

Comment: I see that `error` is used, but not that it's defined anywhere. Anyhow, what would you expect to observe when your program works? Concerning your last question, maybe `future` is a better approach than using a `thread` directly.